# How much promotional language is acceptable in tag excerpts?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

How much promotional language is acceptable in tag excerpts? For example, ['vercel' tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vercel/info):

> Vercel is the platform for frontend developers. Vercel has zero-configuration support for 35+ frontend frameworks and integrates with your headless content, commerce, or database of choice.

> Vercel is the platform for frontend developers, providing the speed and reliability innovators need to create at the moment of inspiration.
>
> They enable teams to iterate quickly and develop, preview, and ship delightful user experiences. Vercel has zero-configuration support for 35+ frontend frameworks and integrates with your headless content, commerce, or database of choice.

I have nothing against Vercel. I personally use it, and I used to be one of the top answerers of Vercel's Next.js. I just happen to recently come across one of the questions which seem off-topic to me, but the Vercel tag wiki doesn't highlight what's on-topic here. Instead it seems like too much marketing talk - like an advertisement instead of an helpful description.

Also, what is the recommended way to handle (or flag?) these?

Comment: More on tags: [What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one). For the wiki the main points are: "Concentrate on what a tag means to your community." (i.e. how it's defined in the site's domain) and "Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag." Esp. the latter part is forgotten over and over again. Also, IMO, the phrase "elevator pitch" should be removed from that FAQ article. That only stimulates promotion which it totally useless in a tag.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've gone ahead and reverted both of these to a version that a moderator contributed.

The excerpt wasn't usage guidance and so is not good; I've reverted to a version that actually gives guidance.

For the wiki, the latest version is plagiarised (it appeared on at least one site back in [March 2023](https://web.archive.org/web/20230324091937/https://www.cockroachlabs.com/partners/tech/), which predates the suggestion). Plagiarism is not allowed on the network. As the prior version was overly sales like, I reverted to the version contributed by a moderator as well.

In truth, as all of these were suggestions (post the mod's version)  likely shouldn't have been approved (the plagiarism should never have got through the review queue). The edit after the mod's was made by a user who works for Vercel; such individuals are normally terrible at making such content as they are not impartial and don't abide by the guidelines for such contributions. The fact it was so sales like demonstrates that. If you do see such content, and the author does work for the company, then flagging or rolling back could well be appropriate action.

Comment: _…then flagging or rolling back could well be appropriate action…_ - Where is the option to flag these? Or by flag did you mean a post on meta similar to how we handle deletions, synonyms, etc.?

Comment: Flag a post with the tag, or authored by the user, on [main] and then give all the details in that flag, @brc-dd .

Comment: "If you do see such content, and the author does work for the company, then flagging or rolling back could well be appropriate action." — I assume this also holds even iwhen the author does not work for the company.

Comment: If the author doesn't work for the company, then flagging may not be needed, @M.Justin , but rolling back likely would be.

Comment: `The edit after the mod's was made by a user who works for Vercel` can we get a suspension or destruction for that user please? Astroturfing is reprehensible, particularly on this site.

Answer (score 11):

In general, when writing these keep a neutral tone like in a scientific paper or at wikipedia. Subjective opinions such as "delightful user experiences" (or "this is trash" for that matter) do not belong in the tag wiki.

It is fine to explain where a certain technology is coming from and post links to it, but not to actively promote it using subjective opinions. For outdated technology, a neutral note explaining how and why it is no longer best practice is fine.

Furthermore, whenever you encounter "marketing" text such as this, it's a big chance that the text is simply plagiarized, possibly without attribution. Placing a random sentence inside question marks and dropping it in a search engine reveals that this is indeed the case here too - this wiki text was stolen from [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/partners/tech/) or [here](https://github.com/nuhmanpk/Awesome-Web-Hosting).

Generally, posting plagiarized content without attribution is not allowed on SO. But in case of tag wikis we typically don't want such posted *even* with sources, because the purpose of tag wikis is to explain how the tag should be used on SO. They aren't supposed to become "wikipedia 2" explaining what something is in detail. All wiki edits posting text from other sources should generally be rejected.